# Error on fetch for angular2-datatable

Tags: angular, datatable, gulp

I am attempting to integrate Angular2-datatable into my Angular2 application.

I am using gulp.

I am following this [guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable)

Looking and following the guide, I run the first command:

```
npm i -S angular2-datatable
```

I then see the following output:

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.4.10
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.4.10
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@2.4.10
+-- angular2-datatable@0.6.0
| `-- lodash@4.17.4
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@0.6.26
```

I then add the DataTableModule import

```
import {DataTableModule} from "angular2-datatable";

@NgModule({
imports: [..., DataTableModule],
```

I then try to compile, and I get the following error:

```
[INFO]  Loading app/main.js
[INFO]  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\DEV\my-proj\trunk\src\main\yo\tmp\angular2-datatable'
[INFO]     at Error (native)
[INFO] [10:26:52] 'build' errored after 7.22 s
[INFO] [10:26:52] Error in plugin 'run-sequence(bundle:app)'
[INFO] Message:
[INFO]     Error on fetch for angular2-datatable at file:///C:/DEV/my-proj/trunk/src/main/yo/tmp/angular2-datatable
[INFO]  Loading app/app.module.js
[INFO]  Loading app/main.js
[INFO]  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\DEV\my-proj\trunk\src\main\yo\tmp\angular2-datatable'
[INFO] Details:
[INFO]     originalErr: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\DEV\my-proj\trunk\src\main\yo\tmp\angular2-datatable'
[INFO] Stack:
[INFO] Error on fetch for angular2-datatable at file:///C:/DEV/my-proj/trunk/src/main/yo/tmp/angular2-datatable
[INFO]  Loading app/app.module.js
[INFO]  Loading app/main.js
[INFO]  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\DEV\my-proj\trunk\src\main\yo\tmp\angular2-datatable'
[INFO]     at Error (native)
```

A similar issue is observed [here](https://github.com/mariuszfoltak/angular2-datatable/issues/68) where the author claims that looking at [this](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Integration-with-AngularFire2) project solved his issue. However, I cannot seem to point out how he made it work.

I tried updating my gulpfile.js to have the following vendor section:

```
vendors: [
    'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js',
    'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
    'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
    'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
    'node_modules/angular2-datatable/index.js'
],
```

However, this did not solve the problem. The error remained.
I also tried to update my systemjs.config.js file, by adding a angular2-datatable entry:

```
var map = {
    'app': 'app',
    '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
    '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
    '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
    '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
    'angular2-datatable': 'npm:@angular2-datatable/index.js',
    'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs'
};
```

As guessed, this also did not solve the issue. What must I do to make this tutorial successful, and be able to use the angular2-datatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem, and I did it as follows:

In my package.json, I had to ensure the following dependencies were included:

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.6.0",
    "lodash":"^4.17.4",
     ...
}
```

In my systemjs.config.js I had to add the following for the map values:

```
var map = {
    'lodash': 'npm:lodash/lodash.js',
    'angular2-datatable':'npm:angular2-datatable',
    ...
};
```

I also had to set the packages to contain the following:

```
var packages = {
    app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    rxjs: {
        main: '/bundles/Rx.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'lodash': {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'angular2-datatable': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
};
```